# Is the value returned by ruby's #hash the same across interpreter instances?

Tags: ruby, hash

Is the value returned by ruby's #hash the same across interpreter instances?

For example, if I do `"some string".hash`, will I always get the same number even if run in different instances of the interpreter? If so, is this also true for all the builtin types (e.g. `Hash`, `FixNum`, etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not the same in different instances, at least with Ruby 1.9.1.

[This link](http://osdir.com/ml/ruby-talk/2009-05/msg00167.html) gives some further info...

It seems that they changed hash algorithm [in 1.9](http://pastie.org/407108) to a random seed-based one...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something that you know will be the same across versions and objects try md5 or sha1.

```
require 'digest/md5'

Digest::MD5.hexdigest('some string')
```

Comment: SHA1 is probably a better deal than MD5 for reasons of being more modern, robust, and cryptographically appropriate.